# Can DART/Dimorphos impact be seen with naked eye?

Tags: nasa, asteroid, dart

Can today's DART/Dimorphos impact be seen with naked eye?

Answer (score 7):

Update:

So, impact done. Some images:

[image]

Shortly before impact:

[image]

Motion clips from or compiled from ATLAS (Asteroid Terrestrial-impact Last Alert System): A NASA and University of Hawaii project, and 1 meter telescope at South African Astronomical Observatory:

[image]

[image]

Image from LICIACube spacecraft's LUKE camera shortly after impact:

[image]

[image]

Original answer:

TL;DR

With naked eye? no; on-line streaming? yes

https://telescope.live/blog/playing-darts-asteroids

https://edition.cnn.com/2022/09/23/world/nasa-dart-what-to-see-scn/index.html

What will be visible when the DART spacecraft crashes into a tiny asteroid

> A live broadcast will kick off on NASA’s website beginning at 6 p.m. ET Monday

> The DART spacecraft is carrying an imager called DRACO, short for Didymos Reconnaissance and Asteroid Camera for Optical navigation, that will share a live stream of images as it nears the double-asteroid system. Those images will be shared at a rate of one per second, providing a video-like experience for viewers.

> What starts as 1 pixel will eventually become an incredibly detailed look at Dimorphos before DART slams into it.

> Also on the journey is the Italian Space Agency’s Light Italian CubeSat for Imaging of Asteroids, or LICIACube. This briefcase-size CubeSat hitched a ride with DART to space and detached from the spacecraft on September 11.

> On the CubeSat are two cameras called LUKE (LICIACube Unit Key Explorer) and LEIA (LICIACube Explorer Imaging for Asteroid). Together, they will collect images and help guide LICIACube on its journey.

> Ground-based observatories around the world will be observing the asteroid system as a way to confirm if DART successfully changed the asteroid’s motion.

https://www.planetary.org/articles/dart-impact-what-to-expect

> Didymos measures about 780 meters (2,560 feet) across, placing its size between Ryugu and Bennu. Dimorphos is smaller than both, measuring just 160 meters (525 feet) across.

Comment: Woah! I must say, I didn’t expect for there to be videos from earth able to discern a plume, but it looks like I was wrong.

Comment: A lot of artists impression before seemed wrong for this - In an interview afterwards someone said that they would have to re-examine their work of what impacts look like in space.

Comment: No we weren't expecting that either... Pre-impact predictions were that it was likely to need HST or JWST or large telescope adaptive optics to see structure.